# Content Headers Remove fails for string Authorization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

The following test fails inexplicably:

```
    [Test]
    public void CrazyAssHttpRequestMessageTest()
    {
        var subject = new HttpRequestMessage()
                          {
                              Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                              Content = new StringContent("some content")
                          };
        subject.Content.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
    }
```

The exceptions is:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Misused header name. Make sure
>   request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers
>   with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent
>   objects.

Why? Any other header seems to work fine, replace Authorization with something else and all is ok.

Comment: Have you tried `subject.Request.Headers.Remove("Authorization");` ?

Comment: @DaveHaney yes, that works, I wanted also to remove from request.content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [HttpContentHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class only supports a subset of HTTP headers -- the headers relating to content. It seems a bit of an odd decision to split them up that way, but that's the way the framework works.

The upshot is that there will never be an Authorization header in `request.Content.Headers`.

You get exactly the same error if you try to remove `"Content-Type"` from [HttpRequestHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [HttpResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or if you try to add an unexpected header to these collections without calling [TryAddWithoutValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875107%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Even more frustrating is the fact that `Contains()` will throw if you try to check for an *invalid* header. You can check for existence without throwing without worrying about the exact type of header collection using [HttpHeaders.TryGetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.trygetvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or just use `request.Content.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "Authorization")`.

The classes linked above have a list of the headers they explicitly support (as strongly typed properties) e.g. [HttpContentHeaders.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I'd add for OP that there is only one place that headers go: on the request. In the code, as @BennorMcCarthy explained, the request headers are divided among the `HttpContentHeaders` and `HttpRequestHeaders` classes (which I personally feel is really dumb), but whether you interact with one class or the other the same thing happens: the header ends up on the request.

Comment: @DaveHaney so basicly using Request.Headers is all I need to worry about

Comment: You still need to use the content headers on the request if you need to modify something like Content-Type.